# Message notification app database structure design

Tags: android, database, database-design, chat

I am developing android notification application. I have doubt in my database structure.

When one user sends notification to other user, I am inserting single row in my database table (Notification) and when one user send same Notification text to multiple user, I am inserting multiple rows in table.

Is it right approach to create multiple rows for different users?[image]

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for that you will accept as the correct answer?  It seems that you are just leading people on in conversation rather than stating a discrete problem that needs solution.

Comment: @DougStevenson. Sorry for delay. But I was studing this [link](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html) which was given by 0X0nosugar.
So I can make sure right approach for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it right approach to create multiple rows for different users?

You are very right in having doubts about this approach. Back when there were no relational databases, there sometimes was no other way. 
If you use your database schema with multiple rows then you will end up storing (and also processing) some values more often than needed. Relational databases were invented to avoid redundancy, because redundancy is expensive in terms of storage, performance and maintenance time.

In your table `Notification` the only column which will not be stored more than once is `ToUserId`.

So I think you're better off with your table `Notification` minus the `ToUserId` column. This piece of information could go into a new table with two data columns: `NotificationId` (as ForeignKey pointing to the notification info) and `ToUserId` (pointing to the user data).

Comment: How is this beneficial to take new table? Can you guide?

Comment: @Nimish Patel - I'm no database super expert so I'd like to point you to some reliable source :) [A Quick-Start Tutorial on Relational Database Design](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html)